# add second independent variable to ode in R

Tags: r, ode

I am using a pharmacokinetic model to fit concentrations to different exposure times.

Additionally to the independent time variable, I would like to add a vector with data for the variable `cw`, so at `t=1` I have the value `cw=41` and at `t=2` the value `cw=17` and so on.
How do I modify the ode, so this actually works? I can only get it to run with one value for `cw`.

```
fun<-function(time, y, parms, ...){
  with(as.list(c(parms.atl, y)), {
    dCp<-(k1*cw-k2*cp-k3*cp+k4*cs)
    dCs<-(k3*cp-k4*cs)
    list(c(dCp, dCs))
  })
}

cw<-100

y0<-c(cp=0,
      cs=0)

time<-seq(0:56)

parms<-c(k1=200, k2=0.1, k3=1, k4=0.1)

ode(y0, times, fun, parms)
```

The code works the way it is written above, now I would like to exchange cw with a vector

```
set.seed(42)

cw<-.Random.seed[1:57]
```

At the moment I get the following error, if `cw` is a vector instead of a number:
The number of derivatives returned by func() (58) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (2)

Comment: You should be aware that the ODE solver will evaluate the function at seemingly random times. The return values are interpolated from the, usually denser, numerical solution that is produced internally. You need to get a value for `cw` also at those times. Best you make a function `cw(t)` that returns the appropriate value.

Comment: I managed to add data for `cw(t)` by adding events to my code. that worked